# Euler's angles to axis-angle conversion

Tags: group-theory, rotations, angle, parametrization

Two widely used parametrizations for SO(3) are the **[axis-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation)**, which can be expressed by three parameters $(\phi,\theta,\psi)$ where $\psi$ is the angle of rotation around the axis defined by $(\phi,\theta)$, and the **[Euler's angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport_chained_rotations#Euler_chained_rotations)**, which can be expressed by three parameters $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is the angle of rotation around the $z$ axis, $\beta$ around the $y$ axis and again $\alpha$ around $z$ (there are different equivalent descriptions of the Euler's angles, use whichever your prefer in the answer).

I know there is an isomorphism between the two parameterizations, but how can I find it?